# How to store a printed value to variable and a new printed value to another variable to use them to compare and find the largest PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, time, repeat, sys

#So basically the following code pulls livestock data from an import called finnhub, and basically, it pulls live values connected to a JSON file using an API. [ The API has no problem the with the code, the first part is pretty much an example of the following or next code which i built] The problem is on the second part, if i could print out a value and instead of it going to to the terminal it gets stored in a variable]

```
import finnhub
import os
import sys
import time
finnhub_client = finnhub.Client(api_key="c82bn52ad3icth8l2dtg")
ticker = input("Type in your stock ticker here: ")
print("|c| means Current Price|,\n |d| means diffrence/change of price|,\n |dp| means Percent Change|,\n |h| highest price of the day(All time high)|,\n |l| means lowest price of the day|,\n |o| means open price of the day|, \n |pc| means Previous Close price|.")
price = finnhub_client.quote(ticker)
print(price["h"])
```

#The h is the highest peak of price the following stock which you chose, has reached in the day,
#so i was trying to look for a way to store the printed output from print(price["h"]) to a variable without it printing to the terminal, then later on after a given amount of seconds a new code prints the same  (price["h"]) to a new variable, then in comparison there would be an old variable and new variable  both consisting  of different values, so if the old variable > than the new variable, it was supposed to print the new variable value.

#So something like this but it didn't work.

```
from hashlib import new
import finnhub
import os
import sys
import time
finnhub_client = finnhub.Client(api_key="c82bn52ad3icth8l2dtg")
ticker = input("Type in your stock ticker here: ")
Tkekr = ticker

def Stockalert(Tkekr):
    print("|c| means Current Price|,\n |d| means diffrence/change of price|,\n |dp| means Percent Change|,\n |h| highest price of the day(All time high)|,\n |l| means lowest price of the day|,\n |o| means open price of the day|, \n |pc| means Previous Close price|.")
    price = finnhub_client.quote(ticker)
#I'm trying to store the output of the first given high peak, then use it to compare it with another value printed after 30sec of another high peak,
#and if it is higher it will, autmoatically send a notification saying it has crossed it's highest peak
   # print(price["h"])
    old_stdout = print(price["h"])
    time.sleep(60)
    new_stdout = print(price["h"])

    if old_stdout < new_stdout:

        print(sys.stdout)


print(Stockalert(Tkekr))
```

#The initial aim was for the code to print out h and store the value in a variable then after 60 seconds or the given time, it prints out another value in a new variable, then the if command/loop comes in and compares the old variable and the new variable, so if the new variable > old variable it would return the new variable to me, with the value it has stored. So if the new value within the variable is higher than the old value it would print  a message saying the highest peak of the day is now "with the new value inserted here".
So far this is what i have written and gotten.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll just need to break it onto two lines of code, like this:

```
old_stdout = float(price["h"])
print(old_stdout)
time.sleep(60)
new_stdout = float(price["h"])
print(new_stdout)
```

This should ensure that you store string versions of each output in the nominated variables. Now, I'm not familiar with the finnhub API, and I am assuming that the type-casting will be enough to make a copy that won't change when the underlying `price["h"]` variable changes. If you find this doesn't work and the number changes to continue to match the variable's current state, you may need to add a `.copy()` method after the float type-cast to decouple your stored values from the underlying variable.

EDIT: Initially missed the less-than comparison. Changed the suggested type-cast from string to float, though this may then require other formatting for the print lines.

Comment: So if i seperates them in two lines of code when it prints the first variable old_stdout it takes to to the terminal and that's the output for that. is it possible for that output to go to a variable to store it instead?  And use that old output stored in a variable to compare it to a new output store in another variable? To be able to use the if command , something like If  old_stdout > new_stdout, then print(new_stdout) is that  it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean. Does the Finnhub API perform additional formatting when you print something from it? What do you lose if you store the value and then print it?

Comment: The finnhub api  is ok theres not problem from there. I don't really loose anything was trying to see if its possible to print and get the value of an output but instead of it going to the terminal, it goes into a variable so i can use that for comparism and print the highest one.

Comment: Oh, you don't want to show it in terminal? Just remove the print line; The previous line assigns it to the variable and will keep it there.

Comment: no but the output is supposed to be stored in the variable then ran again in a specific amount of time then stored in a different variable